# How do I start plack application on boot

Tags: apache, raspbian, dancer, plack

Does anyone know how to start a plack application on boot.

The os is raspbian(raspberry pi).
I think i have run it as a normal user(pi). That's how i start it manually.

I have tried adding something like this to `rc.local` but without success

`su pi -c 'cd /path/to/app && plackup -d -p 5000 -r -R ./lib,./t  -a ./bin/app.psgi &'`

This will in-turn be used by Apache and the app is written in dancer2 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the perl 5 environment variables were not initialised (which are in .bashrc).

so the solution was to run the plackup command inside `bash -i` so that it reads `.bashrc` or set the PERL5LIB before invoking plackup

Comment: `.bashrc` will run when you login [to an interactive shell session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129144/209677), you say _on boot_, not _on a user login_.

Answer (score 1):

On a raspberry pi I use systemd to create and start a service, in the file:
`/etc/systemd/system/dancer.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=NCI Starman Dancer App
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/starman --daemonize -l 127.0.0.1:3004 \
  --user myuser --group myuser --workers 8 -D -E production \
  --pid /var/run/dancer.pid -I/home/myuser/webservers/Dancer/lib \
  --error-log=/home/myuser/logs/dancer_error.log \
  /home/myuser/webservers/Dancer/bin/app.psgi
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then I enable this with `systemctl enable dancer.service`
Or start it manually with `systemtctl start dancer.service`

Instead of startman, you can of course use plackup.

Comment: Just to make clear: `systemctl enable` and `systemctl start` are different and independent things. `enable` means _"autostart at boot time"_ while `start` means _"start now"_. Of course you can do both: `start` for _now_ and `enable` for _autostart_. I think there's also an option to _enable and start now_ in one step, but I forgot which it was.

Answer (score -1):

You may also want to use `monit` or `supervisord` to be sure your app is always run and will be restarted in case of kill by any reason, for example OOM

Comment: Can you maybe add an example?